# How is ping for non-root user implemented on Linux distros?

Tags: sockets, ubuntu, network-programming, ping

I was browsing through the code for ping form [iputils](http://www.skbuff.net/iputils/) package for Linux.


I noticed that [ping uses raw sockets](https://sourceforge.net/p/iputils/code/ci/HEAD/tree/ping.c#l142) `SOCK_RAW`, which any userspace application requires root privilege to use.

How do the developers of Linux distros manage to provide the ping command for non-root users ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ping` executable is setuid root:

```
$ ls -l /bin/ping
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 35712 Nov  8  2011 /bin/ping
```

Answer (score 21):

On modern distros, ping uses an extended file attribute to grant CAP_NET_RAW to unprivileged users.

Example here on my Debian testing:

```
jbm@sumo:~$ ls -l /bin/ping
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 57048 Mar  1 15:49 /bin/ping
jbm@sumo:~$ filecap /bin/ping
file                 capabilities
/bin/ping     net_raw
```

...which is better than SUID, security wise: only one capability here, instead of the full root set (37 capabilities as of my 4.5 kernel).

*EDIT: a couple of things.*

First: instead of `filecap`, you might want to use `getcap`.

The latter comes with the "regular" `lipcap` and its CLI tools, that you are pretty sure to have on your system whatever the distro. As opposed to the former, which comes with `libcap-ng`.

Second: regarding Ubuntu.

Indeed, now that I'm at the office, with a couple of Ubuntu LTS VM (14.04 and 16.04) guests on my Debian testing host, I can see that *Canonical does uses the SUID bit* rather than an extended file attribute. They appear to rely on AppArmor MAC, and I'd say we have a good example here of why this might not be the best idea as a *first* measure: the administrative paperwork load to get it right is high.

As a result, though Canonical do have some AppArmor setup for say `tcpdump`, they do not for `ping` (which is instead SUID = full root power for free), nor for example for `dumpcap` (the process running the packets capture for `wireshark`), which will imply `sudo`, which again is full root power (yet at least with a password). Hopefully upstream developers do things right: capability dropping is available at the source code level both for the iputils like `ping` or for `dumpcap`, so it's up to the integrator (distro package maintainers).

Comment: And caps may be set with: `sudo setcap cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin,cap_dac_override+eip /bin/ping`, see also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389879/how-to-set-capabilities-with-setcap-command