# How to implement the non-root and non-subprocess ping in Python?

Tags: python, ubuntu, ping

I need to implement the ping in my Python application to get an RTT to certain hosts. There are several approaches to do that:

1. To use one of the PyPI packages (for example, pyping, ping, multiping, scapy and etc). But all of these packages create a raw socket to work with ICMP packets. It is not acceptable for me.
2. To create the raw socket myself. It is not acceptable because the reason above. I also tried to create the ICMP socket like this:

   `socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_ICMP)`

   It doesn't work at my machine.
3. To launch the `ping` utility via subprocess. But it works relatively slow and seems ugly.
4. TCP Ping. It is not acceptable in my project.

Can you suggest me a different way how to implement ping without root privileges and using `ping` utility in different processes? Maybe exists some different way **how to get an RTT to certain host**?

Python2.7, Ubuntu16

Comment: The simple answer is you can't because the OS doesn't allow you to. Ping works for non-privileged users by setting the binary to setuid or equivalent. #3 is your best bet in this case.  See this answer for details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37512291/how-is-ping-for-non-root-user-implemented-on-linux-distros

Comment: There seems to be a possibility to receive ICMP packets via UDP socket (see [`ping3`'s implementation](https://github.com/kyan001/ping3/blob/master/ping3/__init__.py#L275-L282).